# Searching an array for term and if statements

Tags: java

I have code that searches for a term in a string and want it to find it then it counts and outputs the total. I am trying to search for another term and output the total of that term.

For example:

```
 for(String[] passenger : passengerList) {
     if(passenger[3].equalsIgnoreCase("female")) {
        allFemale++;
        if(passenger[1] != null && Integer.parseInt(passenger[1]) == 1 {
           femaleSurvivors++; 
        }
     }    
     count ++;
 }
 System.out.println("The number of females who survived: ");
 return femaleSurvivors;
}
```

Now, I want to search for the male and count the times that occurs. Not having any luck.

Comment: what is the structure of `passenger`?

Comment: new to java so i am not sure 100% what you mean?   its reading a text file through an arraylist i set up earlier in my code. i also split the lines up using the tab option

Comment: Your second if condition is missing a closing ) bracket.

Comment: thank you i seem to be missing brackets in a few of my other lines but the code still runs. I will make sure i close them.

Comment: You can write an `else if` statement under the female check that does the same thing, except for males. It's a little unclear what this code does, seems to be part of a function, but in that case the variables `allFemale` and `count` seem to go unused.

Comment: @HayleyGuillou yes it is apart of a function. the assignment was to search for female and male and output the total number of females that survived and the total number of males that survived. i tried the else if statement but i couldnt get it to work.

Comment: I wouldn't think the code above compiles. (indeed, it does not.  just tried it. missing a parenthesis after `&& Integer.parseInt(passenger[1]) == 1` )

Comment: i think i just left it off when copying into stackflow. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would really need to keep track of 4 things, sex (m/f) and status (dead/alive).  You can do it all in a single loop.  Part of it can be captured in the loop, and part of it could be calculated after the fact.

```
int survivors = 0;
int femaleSurvivors = 0;
int femaleDeaths = 0;
for(String[] passenger : passengerList) {
    boolean isFemale = false;
    if(passenger[3].equalsIgnoreCase("female")) {
      isFemale = true;
    }
    if(passenger[1] != null && Integer.parseInt(passenger[1]) == 1) {
      survivors ++;
      if (isFemale){
        femaleSurvivors++; 
      }
    } else {
      if (isFemale){
        femaleDeaths++; 
      }
    }

}
int totalPassengers = passengerList.size();
int maleSurvivors = survivors - femaleSurvivors;
int deaths = totalPassengers - survivors;
int maleDeaths = deaths - femaleDeaths;
int males = maleSurvivors + maleDeaths;
int females = totalPassengers - males;

System.out.println("Survivors (Total/M/F): " + survivors + "/" + maleSurvivors + "/" + femaleSurvivors);
System.out.println("Deaths (Total/M/F): " + deaths + "/" + maleDeaths + "/" + femaleDeaths);
System.out.println("Totals (All/M/F): " + totalPassengers + "/" + males + "/" + females);
```

Comment: thank you. i figured out a way to do by changing my get method to void now it prints out the way i need it to. You have been a big help. Now back to the rest of the code.